# Duh? help with f# option types

Tags: f#

I am having a brain freeze on f#'s option types. I have 3 books and read all I can but I am not getting them.

Does someone have a clear and concise explanation and maybe a real world example?

TIA

Gary

Comment: Possibly see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989264/best-explanation-for-languages-without-null/3990754#3990754

Answer (score 5):

*[Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989264/best-explanation-for-languages-without-null/3990754#3990754) has been rated as the best explanation of `option` types, so you should probably read it :-). I'll try to write a more concise explanation using a simple F# example...*

Let's say you have a database of products and you want a function that searches the database and returns product with a specified name. What should the function do when there is no such product? When using `null`, the code could look like this:

```
Product p = GetProduct(name);
if (p != null) 
  Console.WriteLine(p.Description);
```

A problem with this approach is that you are not forced to perform the check, so you can easily write code that will throw an unexpected exception when product is not found:

```
Product p = GetProduct(name);
Console.WriteLine(p.Description);
```

When using `option` type, you're making the possibility of *missing value* explicit. Types defined in F# cannot have a `null` value and when you want to write a function that may or may not return value, you cannot return `Product` - instead you need to return `option<Product>`, so the above code would look like this (I added type annotations, so that you can see types):

```
let (p:option<Product>) = GetProduct(name)
match p with
| Some prod -> Console.WriteLine(prod.Description)
| None -> () // No product  found
```

You cannot directly access the `Description` property, because the reuslt of the search is not `Product`. To get the actual `Product` value, you need to use pattern matching, which forces you to handle the case when a value is missing.

**Summary.** To summarize, the purpose of `option` type is to make the aspect of "missing value" explicit in the type and to force you to check whether a value is available each time you work with values that may possibly be missing.

Answer (score 2):

See,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233245.aspx

The intuition behind the option type is that it "implements" a null-value. But in contrast to null, you have to explicitly *require* that a value can be null, whereas in most other languages, references can be null by default. There is a similarity to SQLs NULL/NOT NULL if you are familiar with those.

Why is this clever? It is clever because the language can assume that *no output* of any expression can ever be null. Hence, it can eliminate all null-pointer checks from the code, yielding a lot of extra speed. Furthermore, it unties the programmer from having to check for the null-case all the same, should he or she want to produce safe code.

For the few cases where a program *does* require a null value, the option type exist. As an example, consider a function which asks for a key inside an .ini file. The key returned is an integer, but the .ini file might not contain the key. In this case, it does make sense to return 'null' if the key is not to be found. None of the integer values are useful - the user might have entered exactly this integer value in the file. Hence, we need to 'lift' the domain of integers and give it a new value representing "no information", i.e., the null. So we wrap the 'int' to an 'int option'. Now, if there is no integer value we will get 'None' and if there is an integer value, we will get 'Some(N)' where N is the integer value in question.

There are two beautiful consequences of the choice. One, we can use the general pattern match features of F# to discriminate the values in e.g., a case expression. Two, the framework of algebraic datatypes used to define the option type is exposed to the programmer. That is, if there were no option type in F# we could have created it ourselves!