# Erlang: is it possible to write the minimum function as a list fold?

Tags: list, functional-programming, erlang, higher-order-functions, fold

Given a function:

```
min(A, B)  when A =< B -> A;
min(_A, B)             -> B.
```

can I use this in the function `foldl`in a similar fashion to this:

```
lists:foldl(fun min/2, 0, [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
```

I believe it is not possible, because I have to set an initial value that will be compared to the rest of the list, e. g. there is no identity function that I can think of. Am I right?

Syntax is written in Erlang, but should be readable for non Erlang programmers, too.

Comment: Can't you use `head` for initial value?

Comment: I guess I could, and that would crash on empty list as pointed out below.

Comment: Yasir's and Adam's answers are both good, crashing on empty list can and can't be acceptable depending on the context.  BTW fixed your example so it is possible to compile it.

Comment: Thanks, @Peer. Also, I think that `undefined` wouldn't make quite a lot of sense, see, for example, ["Best explanation for Languages without Null"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3989264/298282).

Comment: @Yasir. I agree on that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
1> List = [42,13,25,3,19,20].
[42,13,25,3,19,20]
2> lists:foldl(fun(X, Y) -> erlang:min(X,Y) end, hd(List), tl(List)).   
3
```

Crashes a program on an empty list, a recommended approach "let it crash" as opposed to defensive programming.

Comment: Oops, the last argument to the `foldl` should be `tl(List)` (the list tail). I wish we had the function `foldl1` which is found in Haskell, so that we don't use the initial value.

Answer (score 11):

```
min(List) ->
    Min = fun(A,  B) when A < B -> A;
             (_A, B)            -> B end,
    lists:foldl(Min, undefined, List).
```

Using `undefined` as the initial state should do the trick. Returns `undefined` for an empty list, which is kind of nice as an API.

If you want it to crash on an empty list, use this function header instead:

```
min([Head|Rest]) ->
    Min = fun(A,  B) when A < B -> A;
             (_A, B)            -> B end,
    lists:foldl(Min, Head, Rest).
```

Comment: Good answer! Seems even like the first guard (undefined,B) -> B is redundant.

Comment: Actually just out randomness it does not crash. I don't know if the result is deterministic, but out of the examples I have tried with, a comparison of any number and atom returns the number as being smaller.

Comment: Passing `undefined` works because there is a well-defined order for the `<` operator when working with heterogenous types. In particular, Numbers are always less than atoms. Look up the order functions in the reference manual.

Answer (score 2):

Adam Lindbergs proposal to use `undefined` as initial value has the disadvantage that it generates weird results for lists that has atoms as members. Erlang has a global ordering of all objects, so a nice property of a min function would be to be usable for all types.

I think its more reasonable to crash on an empty list. The difference is that the client has to worry about the case, instead of having to worry about getting a `undefined` as the result.