# Mutually referring cases in Discriminated Unions allowed in F#?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming, discriminated-union

The following discriminated union fails to compile:

```
type Expression =
  | Identifier of string
  | Integer of int
  | Assignment of Identifier * Expression
```

with the shown error being

```
The type "Identifier" is not defined.
```

on the last union case.

I've tried tagging `Expression` with the `rec` attribute but that seems of no avail.

Is there a work-around for this? Better yet, is the referred reason the cause of my trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do that. Inside the Union you cannot refer to another Union element.

So it should be:

```
type Expression =
  | Identifier of string
  | Integer of int
  | Assignment of Expression * Expression
```

So that when you parse the assignment union you can put a validation there that the first Expression in the tuple should be Identifier.

Comment: Argh :(. Now the usual question: why can't we do it?

Comment: Your answer is the right one, but I think he should use `| Assignment of string * Expression`, because `4 <- 5` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @devoured Identifier is a function of type (string -> Expression), not a type. Expression or string are types.

Comment: "Inside the Union you cannot refer to another Union element." That kind of makes it sound as if you tried to refer to Identifier as type from somewhere outside the union, it would work (though I'm sure that's not what you meant). So to be perfectly clear: Like Ramon correctly points out, `Identifier` is not a type, you can't use it in any context where a type is required. You can't use it as an argument type of functions, a return type for functions or the type of a variable. The only places you can use it are to pattern match Expression values or to create Expression values.

Comment: @Ramon: At least in my particular case, Ankur's suggestion is perfectly acceptable. I'm writing a simple compiler, and this is just the parsing phase. later on, in the semantic analysis phase, I can catch those inconsistencies.

Answer (score 10):

It sounds like you actually want

```
| Assignment of string * Expression
```

or alternatively

```
type Id = Id of string
type Expression =
    | Identifier of Id
    | Integer of int
    | Assignment of Id * Expression
```

if you want an extra nominal type for all identifiers.

It is best to exclude meaningless values in the type system when possible ([meaningless states should not be representable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989264/best-explanation-for-languages-without-null/3990754#3990754)), which is why I'd avoid `Expression` on the left hand side of an assignment if your language doesn't need that.

In any case, the reason it's not allowed is because `Identifier` is not a type (`Expression` is).