# F# Options... do they really prevent Null Reference Exceptions

Tags: f#

I am reading the book "Professional F# 2.0" The author shows the following code

```
let a string : option = None
if a.IsNone then
    System.Console.WriteLine("a is none")
else
    System.Console.WriteLine("a is some");;
```

then says

*"this makes the use of Option vastly superior to the use of null and goes a long way towards removing a significant source of exceptions thrown at runtime"*

ok. so I write

```
System.Console.WriteLine(a.GetType());;
```

And I get

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Object.GetType()
   at .$FSI_0008.main@()
Stopped due to error

And I am like 'un!!!"

How is really doing a

```
if a.isSome then
    do bla bla

any different from

if a != null then
   do bla bla
```

So I don't see how is the programmer being saved from NullPointers

PS: NullPointerException has caused me lot of grief in the past.

Comment: The code you're quoting from that book is bad style. Don't do that. The null reference exception from `None` is unfortunate. The benefit of no-nulls applies to the ML subset of F# where it really does help a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add to the answer by Tomas, a major benefit of `Option` type lies in the higher order functions that it supports, that give you more brevity and safety. You might find [my blog post](http://missingfaktor.blogspot.in/2012/02/f-option-cheat-sheet.html) on the topic useful.

Answer (score 9):

The F# compiler does not prevent you from `NullReferenceException` completely. When you work with types defined in .NET, then you can still get `null` value, because there is no way F# could prevent that.

However, when you work with types declared in F#, then the compiler does not allow creating `null` values of that type, and so it avoids `NullReferenceException` in that case. For example, the following code does not compile:

```
type Person(name:string) = 
  member x.Name = name

// 'Person' is a type declared in F#, so the argument cannot be 'null' in safe code
let printName (person:Person) = 
  printfn "%s" person.Name

// Compiler error here - 'null' is not a valid value of 'Pereson' type
printName null
```

When you use `option<Person>` as an argument, then you have to explicitly check for `None` and `Some` cases. This is best done using `match`, which checks that you're not missing any of the cases. For example:

```
let printName (person:option<Person>) = 
  match person with
  // You get a warning here, saying that you're not handling the 'None' case!
  | Some person -> printfn "%s" person.Name
```

The warning tells you that you should add case handling `None`. You can still compile the code, but you will not get `NullReferenceException` when working with F# types if you do not ignore warnings.

See also [this great, related StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989264/best-explanation-for-languages-without-null).

Comment: "when you work with types declared in F#, then the compiler does not allow creating null values of that type". The question contains the counterexample `None` which is a value of an F# type that is represented as `null`.

Comment: @JonHarrop - that's kind of a corner case, though, since the representation is normally only observed by calling .NET methods defined on `object`.  For instance, calling `None.IsNone` doesn't throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @JonHarrop That's not true. From the language perspective, `option<'T>` does not allow `null` as a value (try `let (a:option<int>) = null`). Compiled representation is a different thing, but it only matters for interop.

Comment: @JonHarrop **EDIT** Oh yes, I see your point - the example in the question is a place where the compiled representation "leaks out".

Comment: @kvb Calling `printf "%A" [None]` prints `[null]` instead of `[None]`.

Comment: @JonHarrop - you're right, the null representation leaks through in a few other places too, which is unfortunate.