# Which programming languages don't have runtime exceptions?

Tags: exception, strong-typing

```
string name = null;
name.ToLower();
```

In most languages such code would compile. Which languages would catch this and the like errors at compile time ?

The only one I know uptil now is elm: http://elm-lang.org

Comment: Related: [Are there languages without "null"?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34570644/3425536)

Comment: Are you interested in languages where `string name = null` is not allowed in the first place?

Comment: @zenith I'm interested in languages which can catch as much errors as possible on compile time. So yeah I'm also interested in languages where objects can not be null.

Comment: It seems that a better question title could be "Which languages catch as many errors as possible at compile-time?" in that case.

Comment: @zenith I guess it's the same.You can't go much further in catching as many errors than to not have run-time exceptions. Compiler won't be able to check if your business logic is correct.

Comment: @zenith could you post your link to languages without null as an answer? I would like to accept that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34570644/3425536)'s a list of languages that by default don't allow variables to be null.

This makes them a lot safer, preventing all `NullPointerException`s at compile-time, and clearer because you know where you're allowed to pass null and where not, simply by looking at the code.

Most of these languages also provide many other compile-time safety features.

Answer (score 34):

[**Rust**](https://www.rust-lang.org) prevents a lot of errors at compile-time. Rust doesn't have runtime exceptions (other than [`panic!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.panic!.html) which crashes the program), instead it uses return values for error handling.

```rust
let name = None; // error: mismatched types
let name: Option<String> = None; // ok

name.to_lowercase(); // error: no method named `to_lowercase` found for type `Option`

// correct:
match name {
    None => { /* handle None */ },
    Some(value) => { value.to_lowercase(); },
}

// or to ignore None and crash if name == None
name.unwrap().to_lowercase();
```

One of Rust's core concepts that no other language has (afaik) is [lifetimes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/lifetimes.html), which prevent dangling references at compile-time. However this is something that garbage-collected and reference-counted languages don't need.

---

[**Go**](https://golang.org) doesn't have exceptions. Like Rust, it uses return values to signal errors. But it's not null-safe:

```golang
// strings can't be nil:
var name string = nil // error: cannot use nil as type string in assignment

// string pointers can:
var name *string = nil // ok

string.ToLower(*name) // panic: runtime error: invalid memory address
```

---

The following languages *do* have exception handling but might still be helpful to answer the question.

---

[**Swift**](https://swift.org) is also safer than average, but it does include runtime exceptions. However, Swift's exceptions are more explicit than those of C++, Java, C#, etc. (e.g. you have to prefix each call to a throwing function with `try`, and a function declaration must specify whether that function may throw).

```swift
let name = nil // error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
let name: String? = nil // ok

name.lowercaseString // error: value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'?
name!.lowercaseString // will crash at runtime with: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
name?.lowercaseString // calls method only if name != nil
```

---

[**Kotlin**](https://kotlinlang.org) is a safer JVM-language which also compiles to JavaScript. Kotlin also has exceptions.

```kotlin
val name = null
name.toLowerCase() // compile-error

if (name != null)
    name.toLowerCase() // ok

name?.toLowerCase() // call only if non-null
```

---

[**Ada**](http://www.adaic.org) is a language designed for safety-critical purposes. According to http://www.adaic.org/advantages/features-benefits/, its "many built-in checks allow the compiler or linker to detect errors that in a C-based language would only be caught during run-time".

Comment: This answer is amazing.

Comment: One thing to note is that you _can_ have runtime exceptions in rust if you use `unwrap()`. Similar to swift's `!` operator but much easier to search for and avoid.

Comment: `unwrap()` in Rust would cause a panic, that is program termination, which is different from an exception. It also has the `?` operator which has a similar effect.

Comment: I was going to ask why not Elm but then realised Elm wasn't even around when this was answered.

Comment: @HedgepigMatt Elm was around. I mentioned it in the question.

Comment: @Tomas D'oh! I can't even make the excuse that it was a particularly long question and it was hidden in there somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Elm, as the OP noted, is an excellent language without runtime exceptions. Another language that seems to be equally committed to safety is Pony.

- https://www.ponylang.io/discover/#exception-safe