# CS8602 error stopping me from running Minimal API image uploader

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, file-upload, minimal-apis

I am trying to build an image uploader in a .NET 6 Minimal API. I believe that i have all the proper components but I am utterly confused on the problem that I am having. One specific line in the code has a CS8602 error stopping me from running the code.

```
app.MapPost("/submit-form", async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var form = await context.Request.ReadFormAsync();
    var title = form["imageTitle"];
    var file = form.Files["imageFile"];

    // Perform validation checks
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(title))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400; // Bad Request
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Image title is required.");
        return;
    }

    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400; // Bad Request
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("No image file uploaded.");
        return;
    }

    var allowedExtensions = new[] { ".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png", ".gif" };
    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    if (!allowedExtensions.Contains(fileExtension.ToLower()))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 400; // Bad Request
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid file format. Accepted formats: JPEG, PNG, GIF.");
        return;
    }

    // If validation passes, continue with further actions
    // Generate unique ID for the image
    var imageId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    // Store image information
    var imageInfo = new
    {
        ImageId = imageId,
        Title = title,
        file.FileName
    };

    // Serialize image information to JSON
    var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(imageInfo);

    // Store JSON data in a file on disk
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images", $"{imageId}.json");
    await File.WriteAllTextAsync(filePath, json);

    // Redirect to the page with the unique ID
    var redirectUrl = $"/picture/{imageId}";
    context.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl);
});
```

That is the first MapPost code block.

```
app.MapGet("/picture/{id}", async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    var imageId = context.Request.RouteValues["id"] as string;
    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "images", $"{imageId}.json");

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404; // Not Found
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Image not found.");
        return;
    }

    // Read the JSON data from the file
    var json = await File.ReadAllTextAsync(filePath);

    // Deserialize the JSON data to retrieve the image information
    var imageInfo = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);

    // Get the title from imageInfo dictionary
    string title;
    if (imageInfo.TryGetValue("Title", out var titleObj) && titleObj is string)
    {
        title = (string)titleObj;
    }
    else
    {
        title = string.Empty;
    }

    // Get the file name from imageInfo dictionary
    string fileName;
    if (imageInfo.TryGetValue("FileName", out var fileNameObj) && fileNameObj is string)
    {
        fileName = (string)fileNameObj;
    }
    else
    {
        fileName = string.Empty;
    }

    // Render a page that displays the image title and the image itself
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<h1>{title}</h1>");
    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<img src=\"/images/{imageInfo["FileName"]}\" alt=\"{title}\">");
});

app.Run();
```

The error is happening just above the bottom of the code. in the second if statement,

```
if (imageInfo.TryGetValue("Title", out var titleObj) && titleObj is string)
    {
        title = (string)titleObj;
    }
    else
    {
        title = string.Empty;
    }
```

imageInfo is creating the error
is dereference of a possibly null reference

Comment: we are not a compiler so we don't know all the errors and warning a compiler or whatever tool may throw. Can you please provide the exact message also?

Comment: oh youre right i am sorry. dereference of a possibly null reference

Comment: Well, apparently `JsonSerializer.DeSerialize` returns `object?`, so chances are you get a `null`. The warning just informs you that you should check for that before using the variable. If you know for sure that `Deserialize` allways returns an object, than you may ignore about that warning and use `imageInfo!.TryGetValue`, which is the null-forgiving operator

Comment: Yeah, I simply dont know how to fix it and its giving me a compile time error and not running the build

Comment: Something like `if(imageInfo != null && <rest of the condition>)`?

Comment: That worked for me on those parts. Its producing the same thing on this line now.       await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<img src=\"/images/{imageInfo["FileName"]}\" alt=\"{title}\">");                         on image info. If i was to place that same Strech, where would it go?

Comment: Well, if `null` is a valid scenario, you need to handle it all the way down. We cannot know if that is the case for you. If you know it's never `null`, use null-forgiving as already mentioned: `var o = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(...)!` (the exclamantionmarc is the operator, by the way).

Comment: it is. I ran it all the way down until the point of the final line of code. I am not sure where to add it within that line of code to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature called [Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) which is enabled by default in the "new" application templates. It enables ability for compiler to perform nullable state static flow analysis (during compilation) which should reduce a possibility of ["The Billion Dollar Mistake"](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare/). Also it seems that your application has either [`TreatWarningsAsErrors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#treatwarningsaserrors) or (more likely) [corresponding warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60338870/2501279) specifically because by default this analysis produces warnings, not errors. You need to perform null checks in the `if`s:

```cs
string title;
if (imageInfo != null && imageInfo.TryGetValue("Title", out var titleObj) && titleObj is string)
{
    title = (string)titleObj;
}
else
{
    title = string.Empty;
}

string fileName;
if (imageInfo != null && imageInfo.TryGetValue("FileName", out var fileNameObj) && fileNameObj is string)
{
    fileName = (string)fileNameObj;
}
else
{
    fileName = string.Empty;
}
```

And then fix the write statement to actually use `fileName` (I suppose that was the original intent here):

```cs
await context.Response.WriteAsync($"<img src=\"/images/{fileName}\" alt=\"{title}\">");
```

Personally I would assign the empty value from the start and then used [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching) to simplify the code:

```cs
var title = string.Empty;
if (imageInfo != null && imageInfo.TryGetValue("Title", out var titleObj) && titleObj is string value)
{
    title = value;
}

var fileName = string.Empty;
if (imageInfo != null && imageInfo.TryGetValue("FileName", out var fileNameObj) && fileNameObj is string obj)
{
    fileName = obj;
}
```