# How to get the name of the class property inside that properties struct/class's methods?

Tags: c#, struct

I have struct named "NonNullableString". It throws exception in it's constructor if the string value is null.

```
    public struct NonNullableString
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        private NonNullableString(string value)
        {
            if (value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException($"{value} cannot be null!", nameof(value));

            Value = value;
        }

        public static implicit operator NonNullableString(string value)
        {
            return new NonNullableString(value);
        }

         public static implicit operator string(NonNullableString value)
        {
            return value.Value;
        }
    }
```

I am using it in the classes where I throw exception if the property is given null. For example:

```
    public class User
    {
        public NonNullableString Username { get; set; }

        // ... other properties
        
        public User(string username)
        {
            Username = username;    
        }
    }
```

This allows me to remove the null checks in the constructor as the NonNullableString conversion handles that. However, if there is null value I can't know which property is null because the exception does not state that. `Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: value (Parameter ' cannot be null!')`

Is there a way I can get the name of the property which uses the NonNullableString, in this example Username, so I can get more information when I handle the exception/ in logging?

EDIT: Nullable types are enabled. However, you can still give null value to string as nullable types only gives compiler warning. Above code works perfectly. Visual studio even says that `test.userName` is not null even though I just gave it null in one line above.

```
    public static void Main()
    {   
        var test = new User(null);
        
        Console.WriteLine(test.Username);
    }
    
    public class User 
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        
        public User(string username)
        {
            Username = username;    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is nullable reference types not enabled? Why not use `string?` and `string` to distinguish between a nullable string and a non-nullable one?

Comment: Sounds like you are reinventing the wheel, just use nullable reference types.

Comment: @Sweeper It does not prevent string getting null value as it only gives compiler warning. You can still create instance of the class with null values where property is defined with string and not string?

Comment: @Charlieface Check my edit to original question please.

Comment: @MelihÇoban Yes. Is that a problem? Just make sure there are no warnings and you are good to go.

Comment: You need the caller of the caller as the implicit operator will be the actual user of the constructor that throws the exception. So i don't think you get there without crawling through the Stack Trace. Whats the problem using a better template for the actual property that does that check instead of using an autoproperty? It fells like wanting to use a simple thing then noticing its to simple and then fighting against it instead of accepting its to simple.

Comment: You can force the warnings to be errors and fail the build https://stackoverflow.com/a/62116924/14868997

Comment: `throw new ArgumentNullException($"{value} cannot be null!", nameof(value));` - wouldn't this _always_ resolve to " cannot be null", because `value` _is_ null in that case?

Comment: @Sweeper I am not the sole developer therefore I cannot enforce no warnings rule. It is a good idea to fail the build if there are warnings, however I am not the decision maker here.

Comment: @Ralf There are some properties where I need to do null-checking therefore implementing null-check inside getter or in the constructor I thought it might be a good idea to implement it in one struct/class.

Comment: @Fildor Thanks for the insight, however this is just an example code without putting much though into it for stackoverflow.

Comment: @MelihÇoban IMHO its not a good idea ;) Creates more problems then it solves presumably. To replace string with NonNullableString you need to update every occurence anyway. So simply using a different template for the property instead of just a Autoproperty seems to me the same effort without hacks and you get "obvious" code that tells its intention and can be simply understood by other developers.

Comment: A different approach that might work would be to use 3rd party AOP tools like PostSharp that can weave additional code into your property via attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references) instead. Use `string` to mean a non-nullable string, and use `string?` to mean a string that can be null.

Although there aren't runtime checks when you pass `null` to a non-nullable parameter like you have here, there are compiler warnings. If you make sure there are no warnings, it would be *very* rare to have an unexpected `NullReferenceException` occur. You also have the [option to turn all the related warnings into errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/errors-warnings#warningsaserrors-and-warningsnotaserrors), so that it doesn't even compile.

---

There is no way to do what you want without also changing the call site.

One solution would be to remove the implicit conversion and force callers to use the constructor. This way, you can get the [caller argument expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-10.0/caller-argument-expression):

```
private NonNullableString(string value, [CallerArgumentExpression("value")] string expr = "")
{
    if (value == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException($"{expr} cannot be null!", expr);
    Value = value;
}

// callers would need to do:
Username = new(username);
```

Side note: Your `NonNullableString` doesn't entirely solve the "null" problem, since anyone can use the parameterless constructor of a struct to make a `NonNullableString` that contains a null string, i.e. `NonNullableString x = new();`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I just wanted to know if it is possible. Removing implicit conversion is not a good choice as I need to new NonNullableString every time I want to pass it into classes constructor. I might carry null checking to constructor of the class or the getter of the property.

Comment: @MelihÇoban With target typed `new`s, you only need 5 extra characters. It's not that bad, but I guess you are entitled your own opinions.